# Error while starting rails server : code&.downcase AND region&.upcase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, syntax-error

I am working on a Ruby on Rails project. I have everything set up but when I am trying to start the server by doing "rails s" I am getting the following error:

```
/home/syed/Desktop/offerletter/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/browser-5.1.0/lib/browser/browser.rb:9:in `require_relative': /home/syed/Desktop/offerletter/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/browser-5.1.0/lib/browser/accept_language.rb:37: syntax error, unexpected '.' (SyntaxError)
        code&.downcase
              ^
/home/syed/Desktop/offerletter/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/browser-5.1.0/lib/browser/accept_language.rb:44: syntax error, unexpected '.'
        region&.upcase
                ^
    from /home/syed/Desktop/offerletter/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/browser-5.1.0/lib/browser/browser.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/syed/Desktop/offerletter/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/browser-5.1.0/lib/browser.rb:3:in `require_relative'
    from /home/syed/Desktop/offerletter/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/browser-5.1.0/lib/browser.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
    from /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
    from /home/syed/Desktop/offerletter/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/syed/Desktop/offerletter/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from /home/syed/Desktop/offerletter/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from /home/syed/Desktop/offerletter/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /home/syed/Desktop/offerletter/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /home/syed/Desktop/offerletter/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /home/syed/Desktop/offerletter/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Things thats I have tried:

1. bundle install
2. bundle update

1.Ubuntu version - 20.4 LTS

2.rails - 4.2.2 (have to maintain this version due to various reasons)

3.ruby - 2.2.2 (have to maintain this version due to various reasons)

Note: *Please ask in comments section If you need any futher information from me to solve the issue.*

Kindly please help.

Comment: Safe Navigation Operator (&.) introduced in `Ruby 2.3.0` and you are using `Ruby 2.2.2`. try upgrading ruby to `2.3.0+`.

Comment: @SampatBadhe Thanks Sampat for replying but I have one constraint here. This is a legacy project and I cannot change either rails or ruby version. Anyway I will try your solution but If you can help me with my particular constrained scenario then it would be better.

Comment: Seems to be you have upgraded `browser` gem. if you can downgrade that gem to older version which you had previously, that will resolve your issue for now.

Comment: You might want to ask the author to specify the required ruby version in the gem's gemspec (or open a pull request yourself). It's a matter of adding `s.required_ruby_version = ">= 2.3.0"`

Comment: @SampatBadhe Reverting the broswer gem in the gemlock file back to version 1.0.1 solved that issue. Thank You for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

The safe navigator (&.) was introduced in Ruby 2.3.0, and you're using Ruby 2.2.0.

Please use `try` method or upgrade the Ruby version to 2.3.0+ for using safe navigator.

Answer (score -1):

If the version of Ruby you're forced to use is too old for the safe navigator (&.) you can go oldschool with
`code.downcase if code`
or use the try() method

Comment: How does this really help when the code is in a dependency and  not in the OPs application code?